# How to make a binned version of a barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of lists

```
A = [[8.4476, 1.2896e-06], [8.1652, 2.4992e-09], [8.4757, 3.4313e-07], [8.5289, 2.8196e-09], [8.2903, 4.0126e-09], [8.2122, 1.2891e-08], [8.2598, 4.4194e-09], [8.2133, 1.3551e-09], [8.0199, 2.7166e-09], [8.5444, 4.5322e-09], [8.2125, 0.013257], [8.2465, 9.6889e-08], [8.3649, 2.2352e-08], [8.5861, 2.685e-08], [8.3939, 6.6243e-10], [8.1729, 1.2449e-08], [8.1729, 8.6429e-09], [8.0997, 3.1144e-09], [8.3379, 7.308e-08], [8.3071, 3.3383e-08], [8.5703, 5.1506e-10], [8.4036, 7.765e-09], [8.4314, 2.471e-08], [8.1761, 1.9816e-09], [8.5305, 1.7541e-09], [8.1103, 1.6479e-09], [8.1818, 4.3065e-05], [8.2028, 8.5556e-10], [8.4936, 5.0891e-09], [8.0726, 9.2431e-10], [8.5635, 2.9602e-07], [8.2327, 1.8363e-08], [8.1055, 5.482e-10], [8.2185, 1.7178e-05], [8.1212, 6.7481e-09], [8.092, 6.8427e-08], [8.0496, 2.6637e-09], [8.1818, 4.4151e-05], [8.1028, 1.5019e-09], [8.5635, 1.1081e-07], [8.4396, 7.4304e-06], [8.5011, 0.00048155], [8.1179, 3.244e-08], [8.0888, 2.0115e-09], [8.2783, 2.1645e-09], [8.0069, 3.2472e-09], [8.2028, 9.4631e-10], [8.1818, 4.3449e-05], [8.5635, 1.0127e-07], [8.0726, 1.0427e-09], [8.0542, 2.136e-09], [8.1179, 5.8536e-08], [8.3162, 6.0933e-09], [8.1004, 3.3053e-08], [8.4467, 1.0477e-08], [8.7168, 7.4619e-08], [8.8625, 8.2386e-08], [9.0955, 1.0668e-05], [8.9417, 1.1475e-07], [8.9012, 2.8507e-07], [8.6043, 4.9697e-07], [8.9169, 2.889e-06], [8.6292, 2.3711e-09], [8.8612, 9.6603e-08], [8.6301, 1.5749e-07], [8.8612, 5.4537e-08], [8.9189, 1.1827e-05], [8.6571, 4.5097e-10], [9.0022, 3.7623e-08], [8.8702, 4.1319e-08], [8.6571, 6.9032e-10], [9.0022, 1.2643e-08], [8.7583, 8.7156e-08], [8.6976, 0.021634], [9.2245, 6.5853e-09], [9.2596, 1.4178e-09], [9.7357, 4.5818e-07], [9.7357, 1.5467e-06], [9.2596, 1.0373e-09], [9.7357, 1.352e-06], [9.6335, 3.8465e-08], [9.4126, 3.5259e-08], [9.6335, 2.8004e-08], [9.4126, 7.7311e-08], [9.4126, 5.416e-08], [9.2529, 5.0376e-07], [9.6335, 3.388e-08], [9.4777, 3.0358e-07], [9.2448, 5.8716e-09], [9.3581, 1.3008e-08], [9.3581, 6.5036e-09], [9.7433, 1.1734e-07], [9.3581, 7.459e-09], [9.4874, 3.4768e-08], [9.6671, 4.8428e-08], [9.6671, 5.1251e-08], [9.4874, 3.5968e-08], [9.6671, 5.7862e-08], [9.4874, 4.2036e-08], [9.8819, 2.3973e-08], [9.8819, 2.8353e-08], [9.8819, 3.0334e-08], [10.0615, 9.0102e-06], [10.0615, 9.7216e-06], [10.0615, 6.8295e-06], [10.086, 0.00021523], [10.3562, 0.84578], [9.8411, 0.00087999], [10.3562, 0.8662], [10.086, 0.00044829], [9.8411, 0.00090252], [10.3562, 0.91307], [10.086, 0.00010695], [9.8411, 0.00088925], [12.0191, 0.0068726], [12.0191, 0.007106], [12.0191, 0.0070258], [11.7748, 0.039574], [11.7748, 0.042754], [11.7748, 0.036293], [11.9927, 0.045817], [11.9927, 0.0523], [11.9927, 0.049076], [11.9587, 0.064393], [11.9587, 0.068927], [11.9587, 0.061129], [11.8561, 0.033099], [11.8561, 0.028988], [11.8561, 0.034371]]
```

I would like to plot a bar chart where my x axis is the first element of these lists while my y axis is the second element of these lists. However, my x axis needs to be binned into 7 bins, e.g. [8, 8.6], [8.6, 9.2], [9.2, 9.8], [9.8, 10.4], [10.4, 11], and [11, 12.2]. The height of the bars needs to be the mean value of the second elements falling in each x bin including an errorbar for each bar which is a representative of the variation in second elements falling in each x bin.

The best I could do is to plot all my data points as a discrete distribution. I cannot incorporate the 7 bins in order to plot much smaller number of bars. Your help is greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values can first be put into bins. Then the mean and the standard deviation of each bin can be calculated.

Bars can be drawn using the means and the x-positions. A stemplot can mark the standard deviation. The `zorder` needs to be changed to make sure the stemplot is drawn behind the bars.

Further, the real data points can be added as a scatterplot. Random jitter helps to smear out coinciding points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [[8.4476,1.2896e-06],[8.1652,2.4992e-09],[8.4757,3.4313e-07],[8.5289,2.8196e-09],[8.2903,4.0126e-09],[8.2122,1.2891e-08],[8.2598,4.4194e-09],[8.2133,1.3551e-09],[8.0199,2.7166e-09],[8.5444,4.5322e-09],[8.2125,0.013257],[8.2465,9.6889e-08],[8.3649,2.2352e-08],[8.5861,2.685e-08],[8.3939,6.6243e-10],[8.1729,1.2449e-08],[8.1729,8.6429e-09],[8.0997,3.1144e-09],[8.3379,7.308e-08],[8.3071,3.3383e-08],[8.5703,5.1506e-10],[8.4036,7.765e-09],[8.4314,2.471e-08],[8.1761,1.9816e-09],[8.5305,1.7541e-09],[8.1103,1.6479e-09],[8.1818,4.3065e-05],[8.2028,8.5556e-10],[8.4936,5.0891e-09],[8.0726,9.2431e-10],[8.5635,2.9602e-07],[8.2327,1.8363e-08],[8.1055,5.482e-10],[8.2185,1.7178e-05],[8.1212,6.7481e-09],[8.092,6.8427e-08],[8.0496,2.6637e-09],[8.1818,4.4151e-05],[8.1028,1.5019e-09],[8.5635,1.1081e-07],[8.4396,7.4304e-06],[8.5011,0.00048155],[8.1179,3.244e-08],[8.0888,2.0115e-09],[8.2783,2.1645e-09],[8.0069,3.2472e-09],[8.2028,9.4631e-10],[8.1818,4.3449e-05],[8.5635,1.0127e-07],[8.0726,1.0427e-09],[8.0542,2.136e-09],[8.1179,5.8536e-08],[8.3162,6.0933e-09],[8.1004,3.3053e-08],[8.4467,1.0477e-08],[8.7168,7.4619e-08],[8.8625,8.2386e-08],[9.0955,1.0668e-05],[8.9417,1.1475e-07],[8.9012,2.8507e-07],[8.6043,4.9697e-07],[8.9169,2.889e-06],[8.6292,2.3711e-09],[8.8612,9.6603e-08],[8.6301,1.5749e-07],[8.8612,5.4537e-08],[8.9189,1.1827e-05],[8.6571,4.5097e-10],[9.0022,3.7623e-08],[8.8702,4.1319e-08],[8.6571,6.9032e-10],[9.0022,1.2643e-08],[8.7583,8.7156e-08],[8.6976,0.021634],[9.2245,6.5853e-09],[9.2596,1.4178e-09],[9.7357,4.5818e-07],[9.7357,1.5467e-06],[9.2596,1.0373e-09],[9.7357,1.352e-06],[9.6335,3.8465e-08],[9.4126,3.5259e-08],[9.6335,2.8004e-08],[9.4126,7.7311e-08],[9.4126,5.416e-08],[9.2529,5.0376e-07],[9.6335,3.388e-08],[9.4777,3.0358e-07],[9.2448,5.8716e-09],[9.3581,1.3008e-08],[9.3581,6.5036e-09],[9.7433,1.1734e-07],[9.3581,7.459e-09],[9.4874,3.4768e-08],[9.6671,4.8428e-08],[9.6671,5.1251e-08],[9.4874,3.5968e-08],[9.6671,5.7862e-08],[9.4874,4.2036e-08],[9.8819,2.3973e-08],[9.8819,2.8353e-08],[9.8819,3.0334e-08],[10.0615,9.0102e-06],[10.0615,9.7216e-06],[10.0615,6.8295e-06],[10.086,0.00021523],[10.3562,0.84578],[9.8411,0.00087999],[10.3562,0.8662],[10.086,0.00044829],[9.8411,0.00090252],[10.3562,0.91307],[10.086,0.00010695],[9.8411,0.00088925],[12.0191,0.0068726],[12.0191,0.007106],[12.0191,0.0070258],[11.7748,0.039574],[11.7748,0.042754],[11.7748,0.036293],[11.9927,0.045817],[11.9927,0.0523],[11.9927,0.049076],[11.9587,0.064393],[11.9587,0.068927],[11.9587,0.061129],[11.8561,0.033099],[11.8561,0.028988],[11.8561,0.034371]]
A = np.array(A)

numbins = 7
xmin = 8
xmax = xmin + numbins * 0.6
xrange = xmax - xmin
bounds = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, numbins + 1, endpoint=True)
mids = (bounds[:-1] + bounds[1:]) / 2
bins = [[] for _ in range(numbins)]
for x, y in A:
    bins[int((x - xmin) / xrange * numbins)].append(y)
bins = [np.array(b) for b in bins]
means = np.array([np.mean(bin) if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])
stds = np.array([np.std(bin) if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])

plt.stem(mids, means + stds, linefmt='k-', markerfmt='k_', use_line_collection=True)
plt.bar(mids, means, width=xrange / numbins, color='salmon', ec='k', zorder=2)
plt.scatter(A[:, 0]+np.random.uniform(-.02, .02, A.shape[0]), A[:, 1],
            s=2, color='b', alpha=0.5, zorder=3)
plt.xticks(bounds, [f'{b:.1f}' for b in bounds])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that the above plot calculates the mean and the standard deviation before taking the logarithm. Alternatively, they can be calculated in logspace:

```py
logmeans = np.array([np.log(bin).mean() if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])
logstds = np.array([np.log(bin).std() if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])
plt.stem(mids, np.exp(logmeans + logstds), linefmt='k-', markerfmt='k_', use_line_collection=True)
plt.bar(mids, np.exp(logmeans), width=xrange / numbins, color='salmon', ec='k', zorder=2)
```

Another approach creates [boxplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) with the same data. Note that a boxplot shows the median and the 25% and 75% quantiles

```py
plt.boxplot(bins, positions=mids, showfliers=False)
plt.scatter(A[:, 0]+np.random.uniform(-.02, .02, A.shape[0]), A[:, 1],
            s=2, color='b', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(bounds[0]-.1, bounds[-1]+.1)
plt.xticks(bounds, [f'{b:.1f}' for b in bounds])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot example]

PS: To also calculate and show the fraction of dots above 0.01:

```py
frac_above_1hund = [np.count_nonzero(b > 0.01) / b.size  if b.size > 0 else np.NaN for b in bins]

for x, frac in zip(mids, frac_above_1hund):
    if not np.isnan(frac):
        plt.text(x, 0.1, f'> 0.01:\n{frac*100:.1f} %', ha='center', color='b')
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message when trying to run this script. TypeError: stem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_line_collection'

Comment: Thank You JohanC, I love the second one. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: `use_line_collection` is an obliged parameter in newer version of matplotlib. You might want to upgrade.

Comment: Also, one small issue with the code: we still see outliers beyond caps despite the fact that we set showfliers to False. Why is that???

Comment: The code disables the fliers, but shows a scatter plot of all the real values instead. Just leave out the scatterplot if that information is not useful for your data. The boxplot considers a fixed x to show the fliers, while the scatter plot can use the real x-values. Feel free to experiment until you get the most optimal visualization according to your goals.

Comment: Johan, for method 1, it seems that ax.set_xticks(bound) is not actually producing the nice edde values of the x bins [8, 8.6, .., 12.2] but rather I see 8, 9, 10, 11, 12. What is the reason for that? btw, I updated my packages.

Comment: Some strange rounding seems to happen sometimes. I now changed the code to explicitly set the desired rounding for the tick labels. Probably future versions of matplotlib will solve this type of problem with the automatic tick labels.

Comment: One last question, can we add one more line in the loop in order to calculate the fraction of blue dots ( in each horizontal bin) whose y-values is above 0.01? e.g. a 1d array with 7 elements corresponding to 7 bins with each element being the fraction of blue dots whose y-value is above 0.01?

Comment: I added some code to calculate and show the fraction above 0.01

Answer (score 2):

If you can consider other package, I recommend `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(A)

(df.iloc[:,1]
   .groupby(pd.cut(df.iloc[:,0],bins=[8,8.6,9.2,9.8,10.4, 11,12.2]))
   .mean()
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Quang, this is very helpful,