# Convert multi-variable discrete list of lists into a scattered plot

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists in the form of a multi-value function

```
*[[var1, [a1,b1,...,z1], [var2, [a2,b2,...,z2]],,,[varn, [an,bn,,,,zn]]]*.
```

I would like to convert this into a multi-value list first in the form of

```
*[[var1,a1], [var1,b1],,,[var1,z1],[var2,a2],[var2,b2],,,[var2,z2],,,,]*
```

so I can then plot those as scattered plot and do further analysis with them. Is there an easier way to do it? If not, how do you do such a conversion?

If I was dealing with a single-value list of lists, here is what I have learned (from this post of mine [How to make a binned version of a barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877146/how-to-make-a-binned-version-of-a-barplot/61878267#61878267)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [[var1,val1], [var2,val2], ...[varn,valn]]  # Some single value list of lists
A = np.array(A)

numbins = 7
xmin = 8
xmax = xmin + numbins * 0.6
xrange = xmax - xmin
bounds = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, numbins + 1, endpoint=True)
mids = (bounds[:-1] + bounds[1:]) / 2
bins = [[] for _ in range(numbins)]
for x, y in A:
    bins[int((x - xmin) / xrange * numbins)].append(y)
bins = [np.array(b) for b in bins]
means = np.array([np.mean(bin) if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])
stds = np.array([np.std(bin) if len(bin) > 0 else np.nan for bin in bins])

plt.stem(mids, means + stds, linefmt='k-', markerfmt='k_', use_line_collection=True)
plt.bar(mids, means, width=xrange / numbins, color='salmon', ec='k', zorder=2)
plt.scatter(A[:, 0]+np.random.uniform(-.02, .02, A.shape[0]), A[:, 1],
            s=2, color='b', alpha=0.5, zorder=3)
plt.xticks(bounds, [f'{b:.1f}' for b in bounds])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[[x[0], x[1][i]] for x in A for i in range(len(x[1]))]
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.